# Help need for tridion 2013 SP1 and SDLweb 8.1 Presentation on the same system ( OS :- windows server 2012 R2)

Tags: 2013, web8, content-delivery, topology-manager, dynamic-linking

I need to migrate the SDL web 8.1/tridion 2013 SP1 broker dB to the new server, as existing Tridion_Web8_Broker/ tridion_broker Database are running on windows Server 2008 R2. As you know that windows server 2008 R2 is going to end of support in Jan 2020. That’s why, I need to migrate the broker database to the new OS “Windows server 2012 R2 (X64).

Please correct me if my understanding and approach is right, which I will proceed as follow: -

My question is: - Do I need to back up the Content data store broker dB and restore the dB on new OS or should I need to install the dB from the scratch while running the PS script from the location of installation \\SDL Web 8.1.1\Database\mssql :- Install Content Data Store.ps1 ?

Presentation server also need to migrate on new os windows server 2012 R2 (x64):-

So my next step is to install the microservices for the Presentation server (No CMS involved in my scenario as CMS will stay separate and my CMS is running on different server with Windows 2012 R2 (x64).
So, I will install content services, context service, deployer service and discovery service as a windows service for DXA

Also, I need to install services for tridion 2013 SP1 as some of the sites are still running on legacy templates.
Therefore, I will install the windows service: - tridion cache channel service, tridion content deployer and tridion dynamic linking.

Could you also let me know how to install dynamic linking service “tridion dynamic linking”?

Comment: when you say you want to install Tridion 2013 SP1 and SDL web 8.1 CDS on single machine. Can you confirm if you are currently running TWO CMS ( One SDL web 8.1 + DXA) and other Tridion 2013 SP1 ( Legacy Templates ) , if you want to run both your DXA and Legacy Templates , you can still do that using the same deployer and based on the publication ID you can perform the publishing options and also you can use the content service to read the website content. First clarify which version of Tridion you want to use for CMS and keep the same for the CDS.

Comment: @AnandNS Thank you for your answer. AS i said i am not going to install the CMS for both the systems. My CMS does supports both trdion 2013 SP1 and web8.1. My question is regarding broker db and CD for both the environment(2013SP1 and 8.1)

Comment: can you please let me know the Tridion CMS Version you are currently using is it Web 8.1 or Tridion 2013 SP1 or both if so do you have two CMS Servers one for  Tridion 2013 SP1 and one for Web8 8.1

Comment: @AnandNS I am using both (Tridion 2013 SP1 and Web8.1) on a single instance, there is an option in SDL web8.1 CMS where you can use legacy system. But this feature must be installed at the the time of CMS web 8.1 installation. however, your answer in not relevant to me. I am keep saying, i do not have any problem from CMS side. My question is about CD for web 8.1and tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate the existing broker database, then you can back up the broker database, install it on a different sql server (running on a supported windows version) and then run the broker update scripts (Upgrade Content Data Store.ps1)
This will upgrade the existing database to be used by the web 8.x microservices, while you keep the content within your broker database.

Next, you can then install the different microservices as needed, and connect them to the new broker database.

What you ask about the 2013 services is a bit unclear

> Also, I need to install services for tridion 2013 SP1 as some of the sites are still running on legacy templates. Therefore, I will install the windows service: - tridion cache channel service, tridion content deployer and tridion dynamic linking.

What do you mean with 'legacy templates'?
If these are simply templates using vbscript, then these can still be published into an sdl web 8 broker database. In the end, you just have published content that either goes in the broker db or on the filesystem. The web 8 microservices can handle these without problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Legacy template means which are on vb script and this cannot be managed with Topology. Therefore, In CMS we have an option to enable the features for 2013 SP1 and to publish the content from CMS system it must have own CD 2013 services on presentation server. So, My question is for CD 2013 SP1 is :- how to install dynamic linking service?

Comment: regarding a 'linking service', you have two options, either use the content microservice, which also contains an endpoint for link resolving, or use the in-process api for your web app using the legacy content.
The in-process api contains all classes needed to perform broker queries, link resolving, etc, without having to connect to the microservices. Check the installation manual here for more info (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14)